# Is it possible to partition a MQTT topic with wildcard?

Tags: azure-functions, mqtt, mosquitto, hivemq, mqttnet

Is it possible to partition a MQTT topic defined with a wildcard?
In short, I am trying to figure out if I can implement a subscriber that will scale without the need to redistribute messages. Here is what I mean.

Let's say that I have a MQTT subscriber for the topic `companies/#`.
If I send messages in these topics:

- `msg1` in `companies/1`
- `msg2` in `companies/1`
- `msg3` in `companies/2`

What I am seeing as the default behavior is that my subscriber will receive these messages one at a time exactly in this order.

What I would like to see is for the topic `companies/#` to be split in two partitions `companies/1` and `companies/2`. This way, instead of my subscriber having to wait for `msg2` to be processed before receiving `msg3`, it could process `msg1` and `msg3` in parallel, and be handed `msg2` only once `msg1` has been processed. Obviously, if messages are sent in other topics (e.g. `companies/3`, `companies/4`, etc.), partitions are created on the fly.

Can MQTT do that?

In case it matters, my ideal scenario would be implementing the subscriber as an Azure Function using this Nuget package (https://github.com/keesschollaart81/CaseOnline.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Mqtt).

Comment: The [MQTT spec](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901240) says, with regards to ordered topics, "it MUST send PUBLISH packets to consumers (for the same Topic and QoS) in the order that they were received from any given Client". This is a fairly loose requirement (no requirement for ordering across topics or clients). Different brokers implement this in different ways (e.g. [HiveMQ](https://www.hivemq.com/docs/hivemq/3.4/user-guide/configuration.html#max-in-flight) and this can be influenced by other options (e.g. `Receive Maximum`).